# How to set content inside HtmlEditorExtender on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to set content on Page Load inside HtmlEditorExtender

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_plbNtCom" Height="300px" Width="99.8%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HtmlEditorExtender TargetControlID="txt_plbNtCom" ID="ed_plbntcom" runat="server"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

JQUERY

```
var htmlEditorExtender = $('.ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor');
console.log(htmlEditorExtender);
htmlEditorExtender._editableDiv.innerHTML = "something";
```

I am getting null in Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `getElementById()` to first, catch the control that you want to edit and then try setting the `innerHTML` for that. Something like this should get you through :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("yourControlId");
x.innerHTML = "somethingSomething";
</script>
```

Also, make sure your control is loaded before you call this or you can use `$( document ).ready()` wrapper on this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, it may be useful: https://taditdash.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/set-content-inside-ajax-htmleditor-and-editorextender-using-javascript/

```
var htmlEditorExtender = $('.ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor');
htmlEditorExtender.html("something");
```

Comment: Tried giving me null. I got my answer @HarveySpecter said